# How to set an hourly alarm?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am using the alarm-clock application and the alarm-clock-applet, and the only frequency I can set, are for days of the week. I want an hourly alarm, is there any way to do that? Googling did not provide any answers, neither did AU, seems like no one has asked this question ever before. ATM, I use crontab to fire a `notify-send` each hour. Any other application/methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard preferences has a typing break monitor that can be triggered hourly.  Doesn't trigger if you have breaks in your work.

If it doesn't fit your needs it may be a good starting point to develop your own alarm.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an App request to me Kaustubh or at least a feature request for [alarm-clock](http://packages.ubuntu.com/alarm-clock). In the meantime if you don't understand `cron` you can use the [gnome-schedule](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-schedule) application to give you a gui way of adding your reminders.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below python script not only for setting an hourly alarm, but for setting an alarm with any time interval. Firstly create a new file **alarm.py**, using **vi alarm.py** . Then paste the following code in the file,

`#!/usr/bin/env python2
import pynotify
from pygame import mixer
from time import sleep
def sendmessage(title, message):
    pynotify.init("Test")
    notice = pynotify.Notification(title, message)
    notice.show()
    return
while True:
    mixer.init() #you must initialize the mixer
    alert=mixer.Sound('beep.wav') #name of the sound file is beep.wav
    alert.play()
    sendmessage("ALARM!!", "1 hour up!")
    sleep(3600)`

Here, beep.wav is the name of the sound file which should also be in the same directory as of the alarm.py file (preferably home folder). You can download any beep sound file of your choice from the internet.

Now make the file executable by,

```
chmod +x alarm.py
```

Now to run this in background,

```
nohup /home/'username'/alarm.py &
```

(this is when alarm.py is in the home folder, use the appropriate file address as required)

and hit Enter twice. 
Now this process will be running in background, if you want to stop this, type,

```
ps ax| grep alarm.py
```

and type,

```
kill process_id
```

Currently, the time interval is 1 hour. If you want to change it, change the line sleep(3600) to sleep(no_of_seconds) [IN this case, 3600 = 60*60 seconds = 1 hour.]

Hope it helped!